# How to cast A ResultSet object in to Comparable object

Tags: java, mysql, casting, resultset, comparable

I am writing a generic Java code and i want to add integers to a min Heap which will be stored in a mysql database. For that i have written below code,

```
public void addElement(Comparable value) {

    sql = "INSERT INTO testHeap VALUES("+size+","+(int)value+ ") ";
    try {
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        size++;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HeapMySql.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    if(size == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Shape error");
int index = size - 1;  
while(size != 0) {

        sql = "SELECT value FROM testHeap WHERE indexnum ="+index;
        T val;
        try {
            val = (T)stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                if(myParent(index).compareTo(val) <= 0) break; 

                    swap(parent(index), index); 
                    index = parent(index);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HeapMySql.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}
}
```

This returns below exception in runtime

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:             com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at Lab03.HeapMySql.addElement(HeapMySql.java:140)

I wan to know how to do this "val = (T)stmt.executeQuery(sql)" properly :)

Comment: You can't, because it isn't ` Comparable.` XY problem. `ResultSet` can't be cast to anything much. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a column in the result set (even though there's only one)

```
val = (T)new Integer(stmt.executeQuery(sql).getInt(1));
```

As you commented below, you need an active row in your result set.

You also need to close it after you're done or you'll run out of database cursors.  Reading past the last row (using rs.next) will automatically close it, so I use a "while" instead of an "if".

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
    val = (T)new Integer(rs.getInt(1)))
}
```

Comment: This dosen't work since i have <T extends Comparable <T>> in class name :(

Comment: That just because it not autoboxing like i thought it would.  Try my revised answer where it's wrapped with an Integer

Comment: this din't work either.Later after some digging i found out that result of the query should be put in to a new Result set object.Let's say it is ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql).getInt(1); Before extracting any particular value i should check wheather rs.next() returns true

Comment: Close. I updated my answer for the typical pattern.  Note your original question was about a ClassCastException.  Please update your code as the question evolves.

Answer (score 0):

The ResultSet has all results as an Object in an array, it's not the result itself! You have to cast every single one to the type it is. Furthermore the ResultSet can be used to make easy changes back to the database, too. So you didn't get the concept of jdbc at all ^^ You should read a few tutorials how to work with jdbc in general.
For further help please make your question better understandable. We can't know which line is 140 (from the error), i assume:

```
if(myParent(index).compareTo(val) <= 0) break;
```

Comment: line 140 is val = (T)stmt.executeQuery(sql)